# Links tachados al compartir en Facebook

Tags: php, api, wordpress, http, facebook

Hice una aplicación de Facebook que acoplé a mi sitio con el SDK PHP v5 de Facebook, con esta aplicación el usuario inicia sesión en mi sitio y le doy la opción de publicar en mi sitio, a la vez que se publica en el sitio se comparte en ciertos grupos en los cuales el usuario tiene que estar unido para que se pueda compartir su post recién creado, todo sale bien desde que inicia sesión en mi sitio hasta que publica y comparte en facebook, lo que pasa es que los links salen tachados cuando se comparten, les dejo una captura.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDICION:**
Hola de nuevo aquí comentando los resultados, lo que hice fue verificar la aplicación, para ello facebook me pedía ingresar una url de política de privacidad de mi sitio donde explicara el uso que se le da a los datos obtenidos con la aplecacion, des pues de eso también tenia que mandar la aplicación a una revisión y esto tenia que hacer por medio de un vídeo donde explicara como funcionaba la aplicación con mi sitio web ya que facebook no quiere que usemos la aplicación para publicar sin el consentimiento del usuario, hize todo lo mencionado y me aprobaron la aplicación, pero para mi sorpresa después de todo esto seguían apareciendo los textos tachados :( no me di por vencido y me di cuenta que muy probablemente no tenia que ver con facebook, me fui a mi móvil y cheque el post en facebook y como sospechaba en el movil no aparecian los textos tachados, después me fui a mi computadora y abrí el mismo post de facebook pero en diferente navegador esta vez en chrome, y tampoco había textos tachados, me di cuenta que solo en el navegador Firefox pasaba lo de los textos tachados asi que me dispuse a averiguar el por que, no tarde mucho en darme cuenta que tenia la extención para firefox de Adblock esa extención que quita cierta publicidad de las web, y en efecto al desactivar la extención deje de ver los textos tachados. Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Hola Jose, ¿puedes incluir el código que te está dando el problema para ver cual puede ser la posible causa?

Comment: Todos los enlaces del post están tachados. Más que un fallo parece algo hecho a propósito. ¿La aplicación/plugin está activada/publicada/verificada? No me extrañaría que los tiros fuera por ahí

Comment: Coincido con Alvaro debe ser que se este agregado strike a los textos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Creo que talvez tengas razon ya que es una aplicacion nueva, pero si esta activada y publicada, como la verifico?

Comment: Si vas al sitio de desarrolladores de Facebook, ¿la app aparece con un circulito verde o blanco/gris?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Me aparece verde, estuve revisando la aplicacion y al paracer tengo que enviar detalles de como estoy usando la app para que publique, ya que Facebook no permite que el usuario no se de cuenta de que se esta publicando en su nombre, todo esto es por que estoy utilizando el permiso para publicar en su nombre, asi que voy a mandar todos esos detalles y si me acepta facebook les cuento si se soluciono el problema con esto gracias

Comment: Genial. Pongo la pregunta como favorita para ver los detalles. Añádelo como respuesta cuando confirmes si era eso o no

Answer (score 1):

Revisa tu aplicación, me parece que estas agregando esas palabras "tachadas" dentro de `<strike>` y `</strike>`.

De esta forma se pueden "rayar" los textos, este es un ejemplo:

```html
<p><b>Mihai Eminescu</b>
<p><u>Adio</u>
<p>De-acuma nu te-oi mai vedea,
Rămâi, <strike>rămâi, cu bine!
Mă voi feri în calea mea</strike>
De tine.

<p><strike>De astăzi dar tu fă ce vrei,
De astăzi nu-mi mai pasă</strike>
Că cea mai dulce-ntre femei
Mă lasă.
```

Comment: Esto podría explicar parte de ese texto tachado pero no todo. Por ejemplo, el nombre de la aplicación que compartió el post en Facebook también está tachado y eso no depende de la página.

Comment: entiendo Alvaro, esa información depende de la pagina, revisando la codigo de la pagina   http://mipulgadesanantonio.com  , no veo en el title "esto es una prueba"

Comment: No, no me he explicado bien. Cuando compartes un enlace, sí que Facebook toma contenido de tu página para rellenar la tarjeta, pero otra parte de la tarjeta la rellena Facebook por su cuenta sin importar el contenido de la página web (por ejemplo, el nombre de la aplicación desde donde se compartió el enlace). Uno de esos enlaces que Facebook crea por su cuenta también está tachado (el que aparece junto a "Hace un momento"), por lo que pienso que puede ser que @JoseRodriguez no haya publicado aún su app y esté en modo prueba/sandbox y por eso aparecen todos los enlaces tachados.

Comment: El enlace que usó seguramente ha cambiado. Parece que la nueva URL nueva es esta porque los campos si coinciden: http://mipulgadesanantonio.com/2016/04/03/esto-es-una-prueba/